# How do you fix "code object is not signed at all In subcomponent:" in Xcode 6, Mac OS X Yosemite or Mavericks?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, certificate, signing

When compiling my application I'm getting the following error:

```
CodeSign /Users/pupeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectX-cynmgyozflnwbpamwnpsnhgshuyq/Build/Products/Debug/Project\ X.app
    cd /Users/pupeno/Projects/ProjectX
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "Mac Developer: José Fernández (G4PM7K38JH)"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign A21FB31766DDCBB28FBB4E4DD86E3743024A45F3 --entitlements /Users/pupeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectX-cynmgyozflnwbpamwnpsnhgshuyq/Build/Intermediates/ProjectX.build/Debug/App.build/Project\ X.app.xcent --requirements =designated\ =>\ anchor\ apple\ generic\ \ and\ identifier\ \"$self.identifier\"\ and\ ((cert\ leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9]\ exists)\ or\ (\ certificate\ 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6]\ exists\ and\ certificate\ leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13]\ exists\ \ and\ certificate\ leaf[subject.OU]\ =\ \"XHT4M2DATL\"\ )) /Users/pupeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectX-cynmgyozflnwbpamwnpsnhgshuyq/Build/Products/Debug/Project\ X.app

/Users/pupeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectX-cynmgyozflnwbpamwnpsnhgshuyq/Build/Products/Debug/Project X.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/pupeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectX-cynmgyozflnwbpamwnpsnhgshuyq/Build/Products/Debug/Project X.app/Contents/Frameworks/Paddle.framework
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I'm using two frameworks, Paddle and Sparkle and they are configured to sign on copy:

[image]

Looking for a solution to this problem I found many recommendations to do a --deep sign, which is officially discouraged by Apple ([Using the codesign Tool's --deep Option Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG404)).

I also found the article [Code Signing and Mavericks](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/) which also explains that using --deep is wrong and offers an alternative: using a script to generate signatures for each framework. I think this is something that was needed before Xcode had the option to sign on copy, but I gave it a try anyway. It made no difference, I still get the same error. Looking at the logs, the bundles are getting signed with the "Sign on copy" option, so, adding that script caused them to get signed twice.

My code signing identity is configured as follows for the whole project and each target just inherits it:

[image]

I understand that's not the appropriate signature for Release, but for now, we are just trying to get this to build and run locally.

Any ideas what's wrong? Any ideas how to fix it?
I understand that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was that the Framework, Paddle.framework, became corrupt. The symlinks were resolved to the files they were pointed to, so, compilation worked just fine, but signing didn't.

Re-downloading the framework and copying it into the project fixed the problem.

Comment: THANK YOU. After dealing with this issue for 2 days, generating new profiles, messing with keychain and signing flags and whatnot, this solution was spot on.

Comment: Thanks - i had the same problem using the latest Xcode 8.2 - as soon as I removed PaddleMas - then the problem went away.  I have logged the bug with them again.  This has literally cost me days of frustration.. ( using version. 1.1.8 )

Comment: Same goes for me! Thanks

Comment: this, was worked for me, after remove `DerivedData`, clean project, remove `Podfile.lock` and do `pod reintegrate && pod install`

Answer (score 56):

For me I had to go to the Project build settings and set Other Code Signing Flags to `--deep`. The problem was that my framework in the project was not signed.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when signing a dotnet core application, where the subcomponent causing the message was a .net .dll.

Comment: It worked on Xcode 12 final too, when using a framework from an XCFramework injected through a Swift package. Still, note that Apple documentation indicates we shouldn't use --deep: "Important: While the --deep option can be applied to a signing operation, this is not recommended. We recommend that you sign code inside out in individual stages (as Xcode does automatically). Signing with --deep is for emergency repairs and temporary adjustments only." https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG404

Comment: Thanks for the great tip.  This was very helpful with a Xcode project built by Unity.

Comment: Worked for me in a LÖVE project.

Comment: any chance any of you did this in a CI environment? I'm trying to get fastlane to do this

Answer (score 20):

For All who still are facing this issue, Please make sure 'Product Name' in build setting matches with 'Executable file' set in info.plist.

Generally when we duplicate exiting code, we simply change either product name or Executable file, and this mismatched creates a issue.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks for this check, I would never have found it myself.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the only thing that helped me!

Comment: Thank you so much! Apple's signature policy sucks.

Comment: Adding to this, you can set the value `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` for Executable File in the Info.plist to not have to remember to change it in both places and instead just use build settings as the source of truth.

Answer (score 16):

For me the solution was to re-Add a resource folder (checking Create groups instead of create folder references).

Answer (score 10):

Adding ANOTHER thing to check if you get this error:

In the `Build Phases` pane for your Project's application target, make sure the `Embed Frameworks` phase comes before the `Link Binary With Libraries` phase:

[image]

I'm running macOS 11.2.3 and Xcode 12.4.

#### An Aside:

It's utterly ridiculous how fragile and broken code-signing remains. It's 2021 and this post alone has 87 different "fixes" to solve the same damn error message. There's just no excuse for wasting developers' time like this. Fix your IDE, Apple.

Comment: Agreed - the way they deal with developers is awful. Apple, you are bad and you should feel bad.

Comment: This answer helped. My problem was that I'm using a local Swift package, and shouldn't have embedded it. After removing the embedded content, the Mac Catalyst app builds successfully.

Answer (score 6):

For me this problem was resolved by a simple "clean build folder" action, keyboard shortcut: shift+option+command+K.

Answer (score 5):

I'll admit codesigning is still a black art to me, but in Xcode 6 I found that removing *all* of my signing scripts (which were necessary in Xcode 5, along with `--deep` flags) and additional signing flags, and just using the ["codesign on copy"](http://ckyp.us/1i5vL) option in the Framework's Copy Files phase of the build worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: I don't have any scripts nor the --deep flag and I always had the sign on copy option selected. I can see the frameworks being signed. I only added the script to humor that blog post.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. `sudo codesign --deep -fs cert_name app_name.app`

Answer (score 2):

For me, it turned out that I had inadvertently added a bash build script to the target. Making sure I had no sneaky scripts accidentally copied into the target fixed the issue.

Comment: what does "into the target" mean exactly - what path did the bash script end up in?

Answer (score 0):

for me, one of the frameworks I was including, had another of the frameworks marked as "embed and sign"... which you can't do... only the app should be doing that.
marking the grandchild framework as "do not embed" in the child framework, removed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem after adding `fastlane` to upload screenshots to App Store Connect automatically. I had to remove `fastlane` from the project and `clean` the `build folder` to make it work again.

Comment: so you never got it to work with fastlane?

Comment: Yes it works now with fastlane. The problem resolved itself after cleaning everything and reinitializing fastlane.

Answer (score 0):

Using CocoaPods in the project it helped me to go to the `Pods` project, select a problem framework and set the correct developemtn team on `Signing & Capabilities` page or `Build settings` with `All` levels set.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I both had a subproject and a subproject of that subproject (i.e. a sub-subproject) to which I had added the same Swift package dependency. Keeping it in the sub-subproject and removing it from the subproject solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Product -> Cleanup build folder
2. Build/Compile project

Answer (score 0):

As shown by the number of answers here the causes for the error can be many.
In my experience building a complex project with multiple level of  Frameworks, Static libraries from Swift packages and Pods you should follow these rules:

- A Framework can't embed and sign another framework: only and App can do that.
- A Framework can use a static library (from a Swift Package for instance) but the library must be present only in the Framework and not in the main App. If the same library is embedded in both Framework and main App, in some unknown circumstances, this error occurs.
- Be sure to clean the build folder after each change to frameworks and library structure/embed

Answer (score 0):

Seems this problem will be caused by many factors.
I post my solution in this thread: Xcode CodeSigning Error - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/671238?answerId=763160022#763160022.
Please have a try.

Comment: Please explain the answer clearly, instead of sharing a link. You can look up Stackoverflow Answer Guide.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34915020)