# command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: ios, xcode

**I am having trouble compiling my app after having to re(create) "Copy Bundle Sources"**

**I'm getting this error:**

```
    /Users/lucasnascimento/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newProject-biwbszdogpwqqkdozshnpgrumxjz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/newProject.app: code object is not signed at all
    In subcomponent: /Users/lucasnascimento/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newProject-biwbszdogpwqqkdozshnpgrumxjz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/newProject.app/AppIcon20x20@2x.png

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: please edit your post to state a question, add context and format the code.

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: I think, the crucial error here is "code object is not signed at all". Try searching for that error message. Maybe this question could be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076321/how-do-you-fix-code-object-is-not-signed-at-all-in-subcomponent-in-xcode-6-m

Comment: @mlidal I'm not able find the error message.

Comment: @LucasNascimento the post is better formatted now but there is no question. It is always a good idea to explicitly state a question like _"Is this a known problem?"_ or _"How do I get this object signed?"_. It would also be good to say what you have tried to solve the problem or what you could imagine would work but you don't know exactly how.